# how to calculate UTC timestamps difference in OpenOffice?

Tags: openoffice-calc

I've two columns with start and ending timeStamps in UTC format as follow '2016-06-24T18:22:52.918Z' & '2016-06-24T18:25:03.621Z'. I've around 10K values in each column, but I'm not able to find any clue to calculate the difference between those timestamps in OpenOffice. Please let me know if you know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the later value from the earlier one, something like:

```
=B1-A1
```

Format to suit.